# Laravel Eloquent finding models with more than one relation to another model on another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models using different tables on two different connections, User and UserInfo.

User has a UserInfo hasMany relation:

```php
public function userInfo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('path\to\UserInfo','User_ID');
}
```

and UserInfo has a User belongsTo relation:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('anotherpath\to\User', 'User_ID', 'User_ID');
}
```

I would like to find the first user with more than one UserInfo, however I believe that because they are on different tables on the database I am having issues.

This call

```php
$patient = Patient::with('UserInfo')
    ->withCount('UserInfo')
    ->having('UserInfo_count', '>', 1)
    ->first();
```

Works as expected for other relations and is what I am trying to achieve, but not with this one. The difference being that the two models are on different tables. When I call this in Tinker, I get the error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '(TableName).UserInfo'
doesn't exist (SQL: select `User`.*, (select count(*) from `UserInfo`
where `User`.`User_ID` = `eob`.`User_ID`) as `UserInfo_count `User`
having `UserInfo_count` > 1 limit 1)'
```

Any ideas? I'm very new to eloquent and Laravel in general, sorry if I've gotten any terminology wrong or am missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: please mention your table names in your question.

Comment: Models are always on different tables, that's how it works. I think you mean they are on different databases. Use `setConnection()` in your relationship definition, as in the duplicate. Also note that your code might be better written as `$patient = Patient::whereHas("userInfo")->with("userInfo")->first();`

Answer (score 0):

maybe your table names are not defined properly as standard. so you can use table property to bind table name in model.

### what is the standard to define table name.

Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

```php
/**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if (isset($this->table)) {
        return $this->table;
    }

    return str_replace('\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this))));
}
```

### Example

```
Table            Model
users            User
user_profiles    UserProfile
```

### Alternative

in your UserInfo model

```
protected $table = 'your table name';
```

In more thing you don't need to add with() method and with withCount() method.

```php
$patient = Patient::withCount('UserInfo')->having('UserInfo_count', '>', 1)->first();
```